# Asset Catalog Compiling (actool) fails in Xcode 11.4

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, asset-catalog

Running into this error when compiling a asset catalog with a texture set set to `data`.

```sh
Assertion failed: (maxCountIncludingZeroTerminator > 0 && tokenCount < maxCountIncludingZeroTerminator), function CUIRenditionKeyCopy, file /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI/CoreUI-609.4/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition_Support.m, line 849.
Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code
```

The project is incredibly simple: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zyt5_0MV2BYfb4H2aLGbRO3L-eC3a4to/view?usp=sharing

The project is effectively an empty macOS project with a Asset Catalog with a single texture set and a single texture.

Setting the interpretation to `color` fixes this but this is not very useful. Also changing the target to 10.14 works but it error else where.

This is the Asset Catalogs Tree

```
Textures.xcassets
├── Contents.json
└── Texture.textureset
    ├── Contents.json
    └── Universal.mipmapset
        ├── Contents.json
        └── chest-color.png
```

```
Textures.xcassets/Content.json
{  
  "info" : {  
    "author" : "xcode",  
    "version" : 1  
  }  
}
```

```
Textures.xcassets/Texture.textureset/Content.json
{  
  "info" : {  
  "author" : "xcode",  
  "version" : 1  
  },  
  "properties" : {  
  "interpretation" : "data"  
  },  
  "textures" : [  
  {  
  "filename" : "Universal.mipmapset",  
  "idiom" : "universal"  
  }  
  ]  
}
```

```
Textures.xcassets/Texture.textureset/Universal.mipmapset/Contents.json
{
  "info" : {
    "author" : "xcode",
    "version" : 1
  },
  "levels" : [
    {
      "filename" : "chest-color.png",
      "mipmap-level" : "base"
    }
  ]
}
```

UPDATE: It looks like it could be tools problem? Like I mentioned setting to 10.14 causes the asset catalog to build?

UPDATE1: Ticket Created with Apple #FB7647328

Comment: What is that last JSON fragment?

Comment: @trojanfoe updated the question, that blob is the `Universal.mipmapset/Content.json` in the Texture set.

Comment: FYI, I am seeing the same thing. Initially when I installed 11.4, my projects still built, but suddenly this error started happening yesterday, even for a brand new project with an empty catalog! Even tried re-installing Xcode, but no luck.

Comment: @TheNeil I am also trying a reinstall. Just curious what is your hardware? I have opened a ticket with Apple. Can you also open one as well in order to get this seen?

Comment: Good luck! Mine’s a mid-2012 MacBook pro. Old hardware! Will try and open a ticket in the next day or so.

Comment: @TheNeil thanks, definitely sounds like a tools problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, installing the new Xcode 11.4.1 update fixed the issue for me (after installing it, I did another project build clean and deleted everything in `iOS DeviceSupport` & `DerivedData` from library/Developer/Xcode, just to be sure). Really hope this update fixes it for you too; is a very disheartening issue!

Comment: @TheNeil this has been resolved now with Xcode 11.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Xcode v11.4.1 this issue has been fixed for MacOS applications targeting 10.15.

EDIT:
Once Xcode 11.4.1 is installed you may need to delete the files/folders in the following folders and restart Xcode:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

And potentially:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/
```